# setFrame interrupts highlighting of a row in a QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I am experiencing a weird behaviour caused by [QLineEdit's setFrame](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#frame-prop) function.

In `createLineEdit` I call LineEdit's constructor...

```
LineEdit* TreeWidget::createLineEdit()
{
    LineEdit* l = new LineEdit;
    item = new QTreeWidgetItem(this);
    setItemWidget(item, 1, l);
    addTopLevelItem(item);      
    return l;
}
```

...and I remove the `QLineEdit`'s frame, which ist set by default

```
LineEdit::LineEdit()
{
    setReadOnly(true);
    setFrame(false);
}
```

The Frame is removed as expected, but the highlighting of a row is interrupted (see picture) where the `LineEdit` is. My guess is that this is not a wanted behaviuor. So is this a bug? How can i fix this?
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're showing an opaque editor widget on top of whatever else is there. It's supposed to look that way by design.

If you want other behavior, you'll have to make your widget's background transparent, and that'll only work if the view doesn't suppress the painting of the cell's background. I don't know offhand whether it does or not.

Comment: Hey Kuba. Appreciate your answer again. But i don't thin that it is supposed to look that way by design as you said since it is transparent before `setFrame(false)` is called. So setting or unsetting a frame seems to change the widget's background property. I can not see any sense in this behaviour. Do you?

Comment: Also i would find your answer more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: "I can not see any sense in this behaviour." Well, it behaves that way whether you see any sense in it or not. What's your question?

Comment: Haha you are really one of the rare i-rather-bash-you-than-answer-your-question-guys up here. ***What is the purpose of breaking a widgets background properties by setting a widgets frame?*** If you can answer this: go ahead - it is well appreciated, if not please answer & comment somewhere else. Oh and another question you did not answer in your answer: ***how do i avoid this?***